# Shell Script (Bash): Omits special characters

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a shell script that executes a jar file and stores the output generated by executing the jar file to a variable.

E.g:

```
myvariable=$(java -jar MyJavaJarFile.jar)
```

However the output when I execute the java statement given below consists of special characters such as /, \, +, =, etc. But when it is stored to the variable characters such as \ is omitted from the variable.

```
java -jar MyJavaJarFile.jar
```

If the actual output is `abc=\=abc`, then the variable stores only `abc==abc`.

Could someone help me out with this? 
Thanks.. :)

Comment: Works for me: `x=$(echo 'abc=\=abc'); echo $x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command substitution (`$(cmd)` or `` `cmd` `` (also `${ cmd;}` in ksh93)) stores the standard output of `cmd` minus the trailing newline characters (unless that output contains NUL bytes in shells other than `zsh`).

It does nothing special with backslash. The only characters it may mess-up with are the NUL character (and every character past the first NUL occurrence in some shells) and those trailing newline characters.

```
var=$(printf '%s\n\n\n' 'foo\bar\\baz')
```

Will store `foo\bar\\baz` in `$var`.

If you don't see those backslashes in `$var` that would be either because you didn't check if they're there properly like by using an `echo` or `print` implementation that interprets backslash escape sequences.

For instance in UNIX conformance mode, `bash`'s `echo` gives:

```
bash-4.3$ echo "$var"
foar\baz
```

(the `\b` was expanded to a *backspace* character which when sent to a terminal makes it go backward one character).

You want to [use `printf` to output arbitrary data](/q/65803) (and don't forget to quote your variables):

```
bash-4.3$ printf '%s\n' "$var"
foo\bar\\baz
```

And when that output goes to a terminal, you may want to post-process it with `sed -n l` so control characters or trailing space characters for instance become visible.

---

Or it's because those backslashes were not output on stdout. For instance:

```
foo() {
  printf foo
  printf '\\' >&2
  printf 'bar\n'
}
```

When running that function:

```
bash-4.3$ foo
foo\bar
bash-4.3$ var=$(foo)
\bash-4.3$ printf '%s\n' "$var"
foobar
```

The `\` did not make it to `$var` it was output to stderr.

---

Or of course it could be because they're not output at all as your comment to Benjo's answer suggests, but then that would be a problem in your java application, not `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
myvariable="$(java -jar MyJavaJarFile.jar)"
```

And it should store it as a string which should show the "\" aswell

Comment: Thanks.. But it isn't working for me.I just tried to execute java -jar MyJavaJarFile.jar directly on the bash prompt and its output doesn't show the "\" character as well..

Comment: No, the `"`s make no difference in this case as it's an assignment to a scalar variable where there can't be any split+glob involved.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ahh, okay, now i understand, thanks